# Browse the Active Directory in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, active-directory, wcf-ria-services, peoplepicker

Our Silverlight 4 / WCF RIA Services application uses windows authentication, but for one area we want the user to be able to select a user and further configure the security settings. SharePoint has a great PeoplePicker control that I essentially want to replicate.

Is there a way to browse the users in an active directory share in Silverlight? Or better yet, a people picker control for Silverlight?

Here is an overview of the PeoplePicker control for SharePoint: http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/peopleeditor-control/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this Silverlight TV episode, Deepesh shows how to use Active Directory (near the end, if I remember right).

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-44-Top-Four-Questions-from-the-WCF-RIA-Services-Forum

Comment: Thankyou. From the video I found that in the service project (not the client project) I could use System.DirectoryServices namespace, and query the active directory using DirectorySearcher.